# Grafana Worldmap doesnt show points

Tags: grafana

I am trying to use the Worlmap plugin of grafana. 
I have a ES entry which looks like this:

```
curl -u admin -XPUT "http://localhost:9200"/testmap -d'
{
  "mappings": {
    "typemap": {
      "properties": {
        "@location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'

curl -u admin -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/testmap/typemap/1" -d'
{ "@timestamp": "2016-06-27T12:07:10+00:00", 
  "@hostname": "testhostt",
  "load": 0.5,
  "@location": "gbsuv7z"
}'
```

In grafana I have the following settings:
[image]
But there are now points shown in the worldmap. I don´t get any error message either. I would be very happy if someone can point me to my problem here.

Comment: The ES fields have to be mapped to fields on the Worldmap tab. Could you show what settings you have there.

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem.

Comment: Great! I just put it into an answer in case anyone else gets stuck on the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ES fields have to be mapped to fields on the Worldmap settings tab. In the Map Data Options, there are four fields that should be filled in.

[image: Map Data Options]

These fields should match the fields from the ES query on the metrics tab.